# twitter bootstrap not firing shown event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, colorbox

I have a page/form I'm loading into a colorbox. THe page includes a tabs section. The tabs work well within the colorbox however I need to resize the colorbox once a new tab shown.

I've tried using the sample code from twitter bootstrap:

```
<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    e.target; // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget; // previous tab
    alert($(e.target).attr('href'));
    colorbox.resize();
})
</script>
```

I've placed this in the main page that calls the form however nothing is being fired. I assume this is because the form doesnt exist until called but colorbox.

I've added the script to the called page/form which includes the working tabs but again nothing appears to be fired.

My tabs markup is:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">File/Image Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Files</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">content</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So...how can I resize colorbox when a different tab is shown on the called page and which page should I place the script?

Thanks

Comment: it's `$.colorbox.resize();`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(function(){
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    e.target // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
    alert($(e.target).attr('href'));
    colorbox.resize();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script inside `ready`

```
$(function(){

$(document).on('shown', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    e.target; // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget; // previous tab
    alert($(e.target).attr('href'));
    colorbox.resize();
})

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSpwaA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you = progress made. I've changed the script as above within the form/page. The alert box appears correctly if I call the form/page directly however when it's loaded via colorbox the events do not fire.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3, the following code is correctly resizing Colorbox window on switch tab:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.target; // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget; // previous tab
    $.colorbox.resize();
})
```